# Simple sql solution needed

Tags: sql, join

```
 SELECT distinct denomination,
(SELECT count(com) from security where denomination = 200),
(SELECT count(com) from security where denomination = 50),
(SELECT count(com) from security where denomination = 1000),
(SELECT count(com) from security where denomination = 100) from security;

 denomination | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column?
--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------
          200 |        1 |        2 |        1 |        2
           50 |        1 |        2 |        1 |        2
          100 |        1 |        2 |        1 |        2
         1000 |        1 |        2 |        1 |        2
```

The above code prints the above result. Thats not what i want. How do i write so the count of com for every denomination value so it would appear in separate column near respective number of denomination? i want it to look like this:

```
denomination | ?column?  | 
--------------+----------+
          200 |        1 |
           50 |        2 |
          100 |        2 |
         1000 |        1 |
```

Im sure the answer is simple, i just cant make my mind around it.

Comment: You are looking for a pivoting solution. Most RDBMSs support it nowadays, although syntaxes vary. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: not really sure what you mean, but i use psql.

Comment: It means which version of database are you using.  For example MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT denomination, count(com)
FROM security
WHERE denomination IN (200, 50, 1000, 100)
GROUP BY denomination;
```